# Is $C_n=n\cdot 2^{n-5}$ where $C_n$ is the $n$-th catalan number?

Tags: combinatorics

Is $C_n=n\cdot 2^{n-5}$ where $C_n$ is the $n$-th catalan number?

I asked a [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093090/drawing-n-3-diagonals-of-a-convex-n-gon) that how many ways are there to triangulate a convex $n$-gon where the answer is $n\cdot 2^{n-5}$ it was from [Iran mo second round](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h368207p2026668).But also another kind of counting gives the answer $C_n$ that you can see that [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20806/explanation-intuition-behind-why-c-n-counts-the-number-of-triangulations-of-a?rq=1).But by checking them you can see they are not equal.What's the problem?

Comment: It seems to me that a Catalan triangulation allows for triangles which do not share a side with the $n$-gon (it still has to share all the vertices, though). This means there are more options, and the Catalan number becomes bigger.

Comment: @Arthur but we can solve them both with the same method of breaking into smaller cases and get $C_n=C_0C_{n-1}+C_1C_{n-2}+\cdots +C_{n-1}C_0$ and both have $C_0=1$.

Comment: But your problem does not allow such a subdivision, since dividing the $n$-gon creates two smaller polygons each with one edge that is special in that it isn't an edge from the original polygon. The Catalan numbers don't care, but your problem does, since that means that the triangle that has that edge _must_ have a second edge along some other edge of the polygon. So now we have a special triangle that must share _two_ edges with the polygon, so it's not a true subdivision.